# Evaluation of $\int \ln(x^{n+1}-1) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I approach $$\int \ln(x^{n+1}-1) dx, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

My approach would be trial and error for various $n$ in order to find a general formula but it doesn't work.

Comment: where did this question originate? why do you think it has an elementary anti-derivative?

Comment: It doesn't have to be elementary unless stated. Plus the textbook says it has hypergeometric functions in it(read comments of the answer).

Comment: @user148432: it helps to know when answering whether there is a nice answer. Furthermore, we shouldn't have to read the comments to answers to find out what the question is.

Answer (score 2):

If I've done my partial fractions correctly, we should get
$$
\begin{align}
\int\log(x^{n+1}-1)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=x\log(x^{n+1}-1)-(n+1)\int\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^{n+1}-1}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=x\log(x^{n+1}-1)-(n+1)x-(n+1)\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{n+1}-1}\\
&=x\log(x^{n+1}-1)-(n+1)x+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1-e^{-2\pi ik/(n+1)}x}\\
\end{align}
$$
The last integral is a standard logarithmic integral.

Answer (score 1):

Factor $x^{n+1}-1$ into factors (each of the form $\left(x-\zeta_{n+1}^k\right)$ where $\zeta_{n+1}^k$ is a root of unity). Now, you have a sum of logarithms, each of which can be integrated individually.

Note that $\zeta_{n+1}^k=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n+1}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n+1}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: My previous idea of integrating by parts was wrong. I plugged this integral into wolfram alpha, and the [result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20log%28x%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D-1%29) wasn't very promising- I do not see a nice form.

Comment: I don't see anything standard in that.

Comment: @user173625: ok- let me edit my answer a bit more.

Comment: @user173625: Sorry- I was wrong. I shall delete this answer.

Comment: HIn fact you're right according to WolframAlpha and the textbook result, but we're left with the evaluation of that integral. Noone said the result looks nice.

Comment: But I cannot see if IBP is a simplification or makes it even harder to evaluate.

Comment: I don't think your idea of integrating by parts was wrong; there just isn't a simple general form for the partial fractions integral that results.

Comment: @user84413: Yes- the partial fractions aren't of a good form- and so I couldn't find a closed form solution.